# Use values from object, angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-openlayers

I use a Serice to get some live-data from a client. The live data will be saved in my Service:

```
 @Injectable()
    export class GeomqttService {

      client: any;

         liveData = [
            {
              topic: '',
              timestamp: '',
              payloadstring: '',
              geometry: ''
            }
          ];

    constructor () {};

    ...

    CODE to connect to the client and get the data
    ...

  this.client.onMessageArrived = (message: Paho.MQTT.Message) => {
      console.log('Message arrived: ' + message.payloadString);
      this.geohistory.push({
        'topic': 'temp',
        'timestamp': message.timestamp,
        'payloadstring': message.payloadString,
        'geometry': message.geometry
      });
```

The geometry value contains a wkt-string like  this:

```
'POINT (30 10)'
```

Now i want to inject this points through the Service in my map.
This is not working:

```
import {GeomqttService} from '../../paho/geomqtt.service';

import * as ol from 'openlayers';


@Component({
  selector: 'olmap',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.css']
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
constructor(private geomqttService: GeomqttService) {}

 ngAfterViewInit() {


      let map = new ol.Map({
        target: this.mapId2,
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM(),
          }),
          //vector
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([6.661594, 50.433237]),
          zoom: 3,
        })
      });

const wkt = this.service.liveData.geometry;

      const format = new ol.format.WKT();

      const feature = format.readFeature(wkt, {
        dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
        featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
      });

      const vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
          features: [feature]
        })
      });


// -- addlayer --

  addLayer(url: string, name: string) {
    console.log(name);
    let addedlayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: url,
        params: {
          'LAYERS': name,
          'TILED': true
        },
        projection: 'EPSG:4326'
      })
    });
    this.layers.push(addedlayer);
    this.mapService.getMap(this.mapIndex).addLayer(addedlayer);
  }

}
```

How could i generally get acces to objects or arrays through a service in angular?

Comment: Very unclear, and lacks the relevant code. But usually, you call a method of the service, and use the value returned by the method. That's really all I can say given the absence of code in your question.

Comment: you are currently trying to access the geometry member of an array, which doesnt exist

Comment: @JB Nizet: I edited my question. Do i have to use a method or is it possible to just get directly access to the object?